# Бот в вк не запускается

Tags: python, вконтакте, бот

Я начал делать своего бота в ВК на Питоне. Нашел пару готовых исходников переписал доработал, но после строчек

```
import vk_api
import time

vk = vk_api.VkApi(token = "тут мой токен от группы в ВК")
vk.auth()
```

всегда возникает ошибка

> Login is requered to auth

Уже не знаю что делать, много раз менял код полностью но ничего не помогло. Подскажите!

Answer (score 1):

Никогда не работал с VK API, но Google подсказывает мне, что если в конструкторе задаётся `token`, то `auth()` вызывать не надо.

Answer (score 0):

У меня такая же была проблема, гуглил, вроде как это проблема в библиотеки. Когда работаю с сообществом обычно юзаю библиотеку vk.

```
pip install vk
```

сам код для работы с библиотекой

```
session = vk.Session(access_token='token')
```

Пример авторизации, остальные методы гугли сам, там почти тоже самое что и в vk_api.
Удачи